# Unable to install docker in ppc64le RHEL 8.3

Tags: linux, rhel8, docker-ce, ppc64le

I base on this instruction, https://developer.ibm.com/tutorials/install-docker-on-linux-on-power/ . It is the error:

```
# rpm -i docker-ce-19.03.13-3.el8.ppc64le.rpm 
error: Failed dependencies:     
    containerd >= 1.2.1 is needed by docker-ce-3:19.03.13-3.el8.ppc64le
    docker-ce-cli is needed by docker-ce-3:19.03.13-3.el8.ppc64le   
    libcgroup is needed by docker-ce-3:19.03.13-3.el8.ppc64le   
    docker conflicts with docker-ce-3:19.03.13-3.el8.ppc64le
```

There is no containerd available for ppc64le RHEL8.3.

Answer (score 1):

We have some up to date builds available at Unicamp, try this please:

https://openpower.ic.unicamp.br/post/installing-docker-from-repository/ (edited)